# How to change the background color of "li" items on hover in UI-Bootstrap dropdown "uib-dropdown"?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

How to change the background color of "li" items on hover in UI-Bootstrap dropdown "uib-dropdown"? As uib-dropdown dropdown is generating elements dynamically. Can I have the leverage of using css:hover property on these li elememts.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class, in your CSS file

```
.dropdown-menu>li:hover{
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    color: white!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: white!important;
}
```